# Regex to fail if multiple matches found

Tags: regex, sqlclr

Take the following regex:

```
P[0-9]{6}(\s|\.|,)
```

This is designed to check for a 6 digit number preceded by a "P" within a string - works fine for the most part.

Problem is, we need the to **fail** if more than one match is found - is that possible?

i.e. make Text 4 in the following screenshot fail but still keep all the others failing / passing as shown:

[image]

(this RegEx is being executed in a SQL .net CLR)

Comment: does this support lookaheads?

Comment: After your search, do a negative look-ahead with the same criteria: (?!.*P[0-9]{6}(\s|\.|,))

Comment: @OnlineCop: After is not enough.

Comment: @OnlineCop - Won't work - the engine will simply match the last occurance.

Comment: I'm definitely interested in how this works. However, would you consider it pragmatic to store matches into an array, and if the array is greater than one element + null terminator, it escapes the code loop as a failed state? Just a suggestion, as I don't know how much Tim Pietzcker's working answer works in regards to raw efficiency.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If the regex engine used by this tool is indeed the .NET engine, then you can use

```
^(?:(?!P[0-9]{6}[\s.,]).)*P[0-9]{6}[\s.,](?:(?!P[0-9]{6}[\s.,]).)*$
```

If it's the native SQL engine, then you can't do it with a single regex match because those engines don't support lookaround assertions.

**Explanation:**

```
^                         # Start of string
(?:                       # Start of group which matches...
 (?!P[0-9]{6}[\s.,])      # unless it's the start of Pnnnnnn...
 .                        # any character
)*                        # any number of times
P[0-9]{6}[\s.,]           # Now match Pnnnnnn exactly once
(?:(?!P[0-9]{6}[\s.,]).)* # Match anything but Pnnnnnn
$                         # until the end of the string
```

Test it [live on regex101.com](http://regex101.com/r/nH6aY4/1).

Comment: Also, if you added the `(\s|\.|,)` bit (which can be shortened to `[\s.,]`) just to make sure that the number ends there, you can use a [word boundary anchor](http://www.regular-expressions.info/wordboundaries.html) `\b` instead.

Comment: That's amazing - no wonder I couldn't figure it out though - clear as mud :) Would you mind doing a quick example using the word boundary anchor?

Comment: Sure: `^(?:(?!P[0-9]{6}\b).)*P[0-9]{6}\b(?:(?!P[0-9]{6}\b).)*$`. Note that `P1234567 P123456` *will*  match with both regexes, because only one of these numbers is exactly 6 digits long. If you don't want that to happen, use `^(?:(?!P[0-9]{6}).)*P[0-9]{6}\b(?:(?!P[0-9]{6}).)*$`.

Comment: Genuinely impressed sir, Thanks very much :)

Answer (score 1):

or use this pattern

```
^(?!(.*P[0-9]{6}[\s.,]){2})(.*P[0-9]{6}[\s.,].*)$
```

[Demo](http://regex101.com/r/nH6aY4/2)
basically check if the pattern exists and not repeated twice.

```
^               Start of string
(?!             Negative Look-Ahead
  (             Capturing Group \1
    .           Any character except line break
    *           (zero or more)(greedy)
    P           "P"
    [0-9]           Character Class [0-9]
    {6}         (repeated {6} times)
    [\s.,]          Character Class [\s.,]
  )             End of Capturing Group \1
  {2}           (repeated {2} times)
)               End of Negative Look-Ahead
(               Capturing Group \2
  .             Any character except line break
  *             (zero or more)(greedy)
  P             "P"
  [0-9]         Character Class [0-9]
  {6}           (repeated {6} times)
  [\s.,]            Character Class [\s.,]
  .             Any character except line break
  *             (zero or more)(greedy)
)               End of Capturing Group \2
$               End of string
```